Ogre2 error when running gazebo docker container using headless mode
I am facing some issues since yesterday when running gazebo fortress in headless mode with ROS2 jazzy inside a docker container. I am using ghcr.io/sloretz/ros:jazzy-desktop-full as a base image and I run it with network_mode=host ipc=host pid=host privileged=true using docker compose.
The args I pass to gazebo during start are: -v 4 -r -s --headless-rendering.
It all worked fine last week but I think something changed with the base image / gazebo version that causes ogre2 wanting to connect to a display (see logs below).
I am using lidar sensors in the simulation and initialize the sensor plugins in the world.sdf using.
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Sensors'
      filename='libgz-sim8-sensors-system.so'>
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>

The container works fine on a machine which is configured for GUI applications with docker but I use the same image on a cloud VM where I want to be able to run the simulation headless. Any idea what could cause those issues or how to fix it?
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): eglInitialize failed for device EGL_EXT_device_drm EGL_EXT_device_drm_render_node #0 /dev/dri/card1 in EGLSupport::getGLDisplay at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/EGL/PBuffer/OgreEglPBufferSupport.cpp (line 320)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers. in GL3PlusRenderSystem::initialiseContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusRenderSystem.cpp (line 3434)
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1293] Unable to create the rendering window after [11] attempts.
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1191] Failed to create dummy render window.
gazebo  | [ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1192] Please see the troubleshooting page for possible fixes: https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/troubleshooting

